# Argument null Exception on mvc when using Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, argumentnullexception

I am new to Mvc

I get the following error in the browser window when i used ef to bind data to dropdownlist

> (Error):argument null exception was unhandled by user code and value Can't be null

**Controller:**

```
var ob = db.UserSelectApprover();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = ob.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
Value = c.userid.ToString(),
Text = c.firstname + " " + c.lastname}).ToList();
ViewBag.App = items;
```

**View:**

i used dropdown list inside table tag

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "f" }))
{
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Approver, new SelectList(ViewBag.App, "Value", "Text"),"Select Approver", new { @class = "inp1" } )  
    ...
}
```

I am getting error as

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: items 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: items

All the fields including selected item from dropdown list was inserted into database despite of the error

Comment: Firstly, `ViewBag.App` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so using `new SelectList()` in the view to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is pointless. Its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Approver, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.App, "Select Approver", new { ... })`

Comment: And the error means that `ViewBag.App` is `null`, so I assume this is happening when you submit the form and return the view because `ModelState` is invalid but did not repopulate `ViewBag.App` (as you did in the GET method. Suggest you also read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)